# Why use (360 * 16) instead of just 360 degrees?

Tags: qt, graphics

I noticed this while using Qt, going through the code examples.

When they try to set the range for the variable that stores angle (*angle* in this case), why does it need to be 360 **multiplied** by 16, instead of just 360?

the code (from the hellogl example) is

```
static void qNormalizeAngle(int &angle)
{
    while (angle < 0)
        angle += 360 * 16;
    while (angle > 360 * 16)
        angle -= 360 * 16;
}
```

another example from the colloidingmice example:

```
Mouse::Mouse()
    : angle(0), speed(0), mouseEyeDirection(0),
      color(qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256)
{
    setRotation(qrand() % (360 * 16));
}
```

Admitting I have almost nil experience in both Qt and Graphics programming, also tell if this is common everywhere or in Qt only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buried in [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq11-piemenu.html) article:

> The values are multiplied by 16
>   because [QPainter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qpainter.html) expresses angles as
>   sixteenths of a degree.